# c# flowlayourpanel scroll width

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scrollbar, flowlayoutpanel

I need to change the scroll bar width of a c# winform `FlowLayoutPanel` but no luck in finding how.

Anyone knows?

Comment: Scrollbar width is a system setting.

Comment: @HansPassant if it's parent control supports, then scrollbar width or height can be set..i already know datagridview supports.. and checked to write an answer..flowlayoutpanel also supports

Answer (score 1):

simply setting the Vertical scroll as so :

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<VScrollBar>().First().Width = 20; //or any int value as you want
```

and for Horizontal :

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<HScrollBar>().First().Height = 15;
```

but before this snippet you may need to be sure that there is a scroll bar showing on the control or not..

i didn't work with a flowLayoutpanel before..so i don't know why you use this control in winforms..

but to give you a logic / idea of controlling the scrollbar showing on the control or not..

i use this logic with datagridview..

1-) I, simply calculate the "Displayed total rows height" and "Total Displayed columns width"

2-) if total rows height is bigger than current datagridview height it means there will be a scrollbar..Also the same for the other scrollbar (columns width is bigger than dgv width)

But if you are sure that there is a scrollbar shows on your control then above code lines will set the width or height as your need..

Comment: `flowLayoutPanel1.Controls` collection will not have a VScrollBar control at any point of time unless you add it explicitly to the FlowLayoutPanel..

Comment: @dotNETbeginner As i mentioned in my answer i didn't use flowLayoutpanel in my projects..And as my experience on datagridview scrollbars auto-implement when needed just almost the same checking with my description..So when needed there will be scrollbars..And when no need to scrollbar(s) it would be "null" ;)

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think you can do that in the way you want**. Maybe you can build your own, please take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/customscrollbar.aspx) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/customscrollbar.aspx

There are already a some Q/A regarding this matter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325452/customize-windows-form-scrollbar).