# How to determine the proper maximum value for scrollbar c# .NET (how does windows do it?)

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, scrollbar, picturebox

[image]

Before I go into my question, let me explain my setup:

**First:** I have a PictureBox that holds a Bitmap which is generated at runtime. This Bitmap can be different widths but always the same height.

**Second:** PictureBoxes do not support scrolling, therefore, I have the PictureBox docked in a panel. Initially, I had used the panel's autoscroll feature, but abandoned that after I discovered [through this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e66c675d-dbb8-4a31-849b-df8057a537f7/is-something-wrong-with-the-width-property-of-controls-in-particular-the-picturebox-control?forum=vbgeneral) that PictureBoxes have a size limit. I also learned that it's better to instead have small PictureBoxes and only draw what needs to be seen instead of the whole image.

**Third:** So I added a HScrollBar, which is fine and dandy, but I can't seem to figure out the math behind how big to make the scroller. I tried setting the maximum of the scrollbar to the length of the bitmap, but as you can see the size of the scroller is much smaller in mine than the one Windows puts in if I use the autoscroll feature.

**My question is, what is the math behind the scroller size and how do I emulate that in my custom scrollbar?**

Let me know if my question is unclear and I will try my best to make it more understandable. And thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does your custom scrollbar not scroll far enough to see all the PictureBoxes?

Comment: @Dave, I don't have it programmed to actually scroll yet, but the reason I asked this is because I want the "scroller" to be as big as possible while still being able to scroll to the end. The scroller needs to be big because this application will be used on a touchscreen.

Comment: Aha- so the problem is to do with the size of the "thumb," not the scrolling functionality itself.  Have you looked for a custom scrolling control?

Comment: Correct! Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325452/customize-windows-form-scrollbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem. Perhaps I should have tried a little longer. :)

The answer lies in the `LargeChange` property. I let the `Maximum` at the total width of the bitmap and then  set the `LargeChange` to the width of what I wanted to show. (i.e. the width of the PictureBox)

The size of the "scroller" is determined by the ratio of the value of `LargeChange` to the value of `Maximum`. For example, if the width to show (`LargeChange`) is 100 and the total width (`Maximum`) is 300 then the "scroller" size will be 1/3 of the scrollbar length. (100/300).

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem too and tried to figure it out, I have a panel which contain another panel inside it called panelChild, and the default scrollbar is small, I need lager scrollbar, so I use HScrollBar to do that (display over-top of default scrollbar), I post my solution here, may be it helpful to someone

```
public Form() {
    InitializeComponent();

    hScrollBar.Maximum = panelChild.Width;
    hScrollBar.LargeChange = panel.Width; // panel which contain panelChild, and this hScrollBar will same as panel scrollbar
    hScrollBar.Scroll += HScrollBar_Scroll;
}

private void HScrollBar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    int diference = e.OldValue - e.NewValue;
    foreach (Control c in panel.Controls)
    {
         c.Location = new Point(c.Location.X + diference, c.Location.Y);
    }
}
```