# How to Create WPF like Scrollbar Custom Control for Winforms

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, winforms, scrollbar

I have a scenario in which I have to change the theme of Winform to WPF like .

But existing functionality remains same as it is.I have a **Grid-view** and two buttons for controlling the scroll, but now I have to add a scroll control to handle the scroll functionality.

Anybody suggest the best way to start with.
I am attaching an image.[image]

The possible answer is simple copy of scrollbar that we use in Windows, it has, Thumb and up down arrows, but my requirements are different, I need the scrollbar which works with "DataGridView".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize Windows Form Scrollbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325452/customize-windows-form-scrollbar)

Comment: may be, but i have seen that, it was not what i wanted to, i have worked with it too.

Comment: WinForms is just the wrong technology to use if skinning the gui is important.